# 【nginx】How to compare a ip in nginx with ip from a file

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  abc.com.com;
    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log  /data/logs/error.log;
    
    location / {

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           if ($remote_addr ~ "202.96.134.100") 
              {
                      proxy_pass http://abc_test_server;
                       break;
               }
    proxy_pass http://abc_server;
    }
}
```

for this part

> if ($remote_addr ~ "202.96.134.100")

I want to read the ip in a file, is it possiable in nginx ?

Comment: Thats not possible, where is the diffrence if you write in a external file or the nginx config ?

Comment: yes, I have many config files to manage, if I want to add some ip, i need to edit all of them :(

Comment: closest is probably to use [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include)

Comment: You can also "include" a file using the [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).